# Create a computed Knockout observable based on Rxjs behaviour subject

Tags: knockout.js, rxjs

I'm trying to convert a Knockout code to Rxjs. (Each time changing a different part)

The part I wish to change next:

```
   _this.firstObs =  ko.observable();
   _this.secondObs = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var first = _this.firstObs();
            return first && first.innerObs();
        },
        deferEvaluation: true,
    });
```

I tried to convert firstObs to Rxjs, meaning the new code is:

```
    _this.firstObs =  new Rx.BehaviorSubject(undefined);
    _this.secondObs = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var first = _this.firstObs.getValue();
            return first && first.innerObs();
        },
        deferEvaluation: true,
    });
```

But, when debugging it seems the the read function isn't triggered when firstObs emits a value (_this.firstObs.next(<...>)).

Is it there an option to create a computed Knockout observable based on Rxjs?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve?  E.g. What do you expect `secondObs` to emit for each value that is emitted form `firstObs`? I assume you want to filter for values that are not `null` or `undefined`, is that correct?

Comment: For each `firstObs` emitted value, I want `secondObs` to be the innerObservable indise `firstObj`; (if `firstObs` is null/undefined I would like `secondObs` to be undefined too )
In general I would like to convert firstObs to a Rxjs subject/behavior subject, but with minimal code changes( I was hoping there is a way to do so without converting secondObs/innerObs to rxjs too)
,

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to mix Rxjs observables and Knockout observables. I don‘t think this is possible. Nevertheless in order to create „computed“ observables in rxjs you can just `.pipe` your initial observable to operators, which will then return a new „computed“ observable. In order for me to help you with such a pipe, you should include example values in your question.

Comment: Ok. The reason is that I need to use Rxjs instead of Knockout as part of code refactoring, and I didn't want to change the entire code at once, so I was hoping it is possible to mix. Thanks :)

Comment: I think it would be more difficult to mix these two things instead of adapting all at once. Nevertheless I would be glad if I could help you with defining the pipe to get the results needed. Unfortunately it is not yet clear to me what exactly `secondObs` should represent. If you could clarify, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, for my team, we decided to change the approach and quit using the observables, so we converted the computed observables to functions. Otherwise, we would have converted all of the KO observables to Rxjs Observables at once (to avoid mixing issues), as @Fabian Strathaus suggested. Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).